# How can I cast LinearLayout with CalendarView?

Tags: android, android-activity, casting, android-linearlayout, calendarview

I want to use `CalenderView` on my activity, I also try to clean my project but this problem not solved.

This is my code:

Cal_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="264dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.malik.auealert.HistoryActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        layout="@layout/cal_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ActivityClass:

```
public CalendarView c;
// public TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    // LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) View v;
    /* ***ERROR Appear on here***: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.CalendarView */
    c = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    //t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

    c.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        }
    });
```

I searched Google for a solution, but couldn't find one.

Comment: `R.id.calendarView` is not the correct id of your calendarview, in fact your calendarview does not even have an id

Comment: If you include a `LinearLayout`, then assign to it the id `calendarView`, then look that view up and cast it to a `CalendarView`, when the error says "cannot be cast to CalendarView", what do you think is the problem?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Thanks for your reply I want to know how this problem can be solved ?

Comment: @tyczj Thanks for your reply, so how we can get CalenderView in our Activity if it has no id?

Comment: you put an id in and then use it....

Comment: @tyczj Thanks alot it's work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with giving *android:id* to **CalenderView** and map that id with **CalenderView** in **ActivityClass**.

```
<CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="264dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

first assign id to calendarView like below example.

`<CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="264dp" />`

than find your included view as shown below.

View includedView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

CalendarView = (CalendarView) includedView.findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);